# Expressing age between two years

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Question

How could I express the following statement in my query?

```
Between 4 and 5 years old
```

### SQL Query

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) <=2
```

Get all Assets that are more than one year old from todays date

### What I want to say?

Get all assets between 4 and 5 years old

---

Comment: is this something like `WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) between 4 and 5`.

Comment: Do you want the exact age of the person? In other words do you consider someone born on 2010-12-12 a 4 year old or a 3 year old?

Comment: "Between 4 and 5 years old" is quite ambiguous.  Can you edit the question and give examples of dates that meet and fail this condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be very careful using `datediff(year)`.  It counts the number of year boundaries between two dates.  So, the difference between 2014-12-31 and 2015-01-01 is 1.

In addition, I recommend putting the functions on the `getdate()` value rather than on the column.  This allows an index to still be used on the column ("sargability").  So, something like this should do what you want:

```
where AcquiredDate >= dateadd(year, -5, GetDate()) and
      AcquiredDate < dateadd(year , -3, GetDate())
```

On 2015-01-01, this will retrieve rows acquired between 2010-01-1 and 2011-12-31, which seems to be the intent of the question.

Comment: I agree. Using datediff can result in incorrect data.

Answer (score 3):

check for SQL's BETWEEN OPERATOR here
[SQL Between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE NAME WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) BETWEEN 4 and 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, AcquiredDate, GetDate()) BETWEEN 4 and 5
```